# swift: Centre alignment for the text of labels and buttons

Tags: ios, swift

Programmatically i have created a View and added a label and buttons to it. its fine in vertical it aligns to centre but as i rotate the screen it does not aligns to centre rather it seems as left aligned.

This is my code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {


    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 150))
    headerView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    headerView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    headerView.backgroundColor = ClientConfiguration.primaryUIColor()

    let myLabel = UILabel()
    myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(-1, -1, tableView.frame.width, 30)
    myLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14)
    myLabel.backgroundColor =  ClientConfiguration.primaryUIColor()
    myLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    myLabel.text = "Select Time Zone"
    myLabel.textAlignment = .Center

    let frame = CGRectMake(1, 1,headerView.frame.width , 70)
    self.btnTimeZone.frame = frame
    headerView.addSubview(myLabel)
    headerView.addSubview(self.btnTimeZone)

    self.buttonTitileString = self.selectedZone.value       
    self.btnTimeZone.setTitle(buttonTitileString, forState: .Normal)

    return headerView

}
```

[In horizontal mode the button text and label are aligned to left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUuP4.png)

and when i set  `self.btnTimeZone.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Center`

its fine in horizontal mode but in vertical mode they all are right aligned as;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hk8rq.png)

How can i solve this issue i need both of them in centre aligned in both horizontal and vertical mode.

Comment: you will probably have to recalculate the frame when the orientation changes. when you change the orientation, the width changes to height and vice versa. if you upload the sample project, maybe I can take a better look at it. also, why are you not using autolayout?

Comment: This is all i have done to create the view Programitically .

Answer (score 2):

You just need to reload the table when rotate the phone. Implement following method and inside of this method reload the tableView

```
    override func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {

       tableView.reloadData()

   }
```

Comment: is this method will be called automatically.?

Comment: yeah. implement it inside of ViewController. comment if u have any issue

Comment: isn't it call when u rotating

Answer (score 1):

In case of the application should support both portrait and landscape modes, the good approach would be to work with [`NSLayoutConstraint`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nslayoutconstraint).

Of course you have both options to create them programmatically or from the Interface Builder, I'd like to note that you are able to create the header view as a cell, without the need of doing it programmatically; That's -obviously- will leads to the ease of setup the desired constrains for the header subviews.

Comment: can you edit above my codes and show where am i wrong..?

Comment: To make sure that I will give a useful answer, I'd suggest to add it as a cell (from storyboard) instead of doing it programmatically. Is it required to do it programmatically?

Comment: I will edit my answer to show you how could you do it via interface builder. another thing to check, in `cellForRow` method, are you getting the cell from a separated *.xib* file or the cell is included in the tableview?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set autoresizing for parent view.

```
headerView.autoresizesSubviews = true
myLabel.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
self.btnTimeZone.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

Comment: This should used before returning the header view

Comment: still same problem

Comment: @iron, try to change values in autoresizingMask array on values from [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewautoresizing). Try to use margin values

Comment: @iron I made mistake, `autoresizingMask` should be setted for subviews

Answer (score 0):

Try this also

change

```
tableView.frame.width
```

to

```
tableView.frame.size.width
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 5 (and 3, 4 too) you got to override viewDidLayoutSubviews() method of life cycle of view controller, it calls after viewWillTransition() method when rotating your device.

In viewDidLayoutSubviews() method you just need to reload the data of your tableView in order to redraw your section header for portrait to landscape or landscape to portrait, and it works perfectly.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Thanks to GayashanK for give me this idea with his answer.